# ExpandableListView not showing in TabHost in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, expandablelistview

As stated in the title, I have an `ExpandableListView` inside of a `TabHost` which is being loaded from a `Fragment`

I can get the `ExpandableListView` to show properly without the `TabHost` but once I added the `TabHost` it doesn't show.

I've also gotten it so that when I change tabs the list will show, but upon initial load of the view the `ExpandableListView` is not there.

Here's the code:

```
public class Categories extends Fragment {

    SearchView searchView; //Not doing anything yet
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    TabHost tabHost;  

    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childTitles = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_tabs, null);
        searchView = (SearchView) layout.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        this.inflater = inflater;

        tabHost = (TabHost) layout.findViewById(R.id.tabhost); // The activity TabHost
        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Reusable TabSpec for each intent;

        try
        {
            //setup tab name, display text, and layout
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.events))
                .setIndicator(" " + getResources().getString(R.string.events) + " ")
                .setContent(R.id.categoriesLayout); //must be id, not layout or xml

            //add tab
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.venues))
                .setIndicator(" " + getResources().getString(R.string.venues) + " ")
                .setContent(R.id.categoriesLayout); //must be id, not layout or xml


            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            //finish adding tabs
            tabHost.getTabWidget();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "Failed to load tab host");
        }

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String s) 
            {
                displayTab();
            }
        });

        return layout;
    }

    private void displayTab()
    {
        //set parentItems - not shown
        setGroupParents();

        //set childTitles - not shown
        setChildData();


        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childTitles, childDescriptions);
        adapter.setInflater(inflater, getActivity());
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        displayTab();
    }
```

Running the `displayTab` function shows the `ExpandableListView` when switching tabs, but I need it to show the list immediately upon loading the screen. What am I doing wrong?

**ADDENDUM**

OK, so now I'm really confused... if I put

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

in my `onStart()`, the `ExpandableListView` shows, but if I just put

```
displayTab();
```

in there, it doesn't show. All that the `OnTabChangeListener` is doing is running `displayTab`...

Answer (score 0):

you working on the ExpendableListView after the view has been created, thats not necessary, you can do your work in onCreateView. Maybe calling notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter in displayTab() is sufficient.

or you could just move your code to the proper callback.

If that doesnt help, show your adapter code please

So what happens if tab has changed is, that it calles displayTab explicitly. did you ensure that the Method is called upon first initialization? and i mean verified that i runs? like sysout(running)?

Comment: I've tried doing the work on `ExpandableListView` before the view is created, after the view is created, after the activity is created... nothing seems to work. 

Also, I tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged`, no luck :-(

Comment: I verified that the method is running and that the variables are being set. The adapter is getting the information that it needs, and is being set to the `ExpandableListView`... everything is happening as it should, but the list view is never displayed in the initial load of the fragment